# asp.net custom validator question

Tags: asp.net

I am familiar with how to write and use custom validators for the simple cases (i.e. making sure that a date is greater than or equal to some value).

How would you approach this type of (common) scenario:

I have a drop-down list with 5 choices, depending on which choice is selected, several other fields need to be validated. For example, if choice "3" is made from the drop down, I need to make sure fields a,b,c are filled in, but if choice "2" is made from the drop down I need to make sure a,b are blank and e,f are filled in etc.

I guess the question is, does the custom validator get associated with the drop down list, or do you put a custom validator on all of the fields a/b/c/d/e/f etc...or is there the concept of a form-level custom validator that I can have called?

Probably at least ten different ways to do this, but looking for the cleanest option.

Comment: Is this validation you do on the client or server-side?  In other wodrs, is the AutoPostBack property of the DropDownList set to true?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of using the MS AJAX toolkit you can make something that'll do what what you want quickly (if perhaps not the greatest in performance friendliness).

Create several different custom validators each representing the different validation goals associated with the drop down list items.  Set each validator's Enabled property to false.

Have the drop down list autopostback on change and alter which validator is Enabled based on the selected value.

Enclose all of this in an `UpdatePanel` for smooth UI.

Another approach involves jQuery and one of the validation plugins.  You'll just have to spend a short amount of time accustoming yourself to whichever validation plugin you go with.  (I like this approach because its highly re-usable across different web dev platforms.)  Ultimately you will have a client-side event attached to the drop down list to add or remove CSS styles to your different fields; however remember to program defensively and include server side validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recently **[answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410054/how-to-validation-when-other-option-in-dropdownlist-is-selected-text-is-entered/1410538#1410538)** that dealt with 1 field. You should be able to extend it to check for the various selections, then check if the associated fields have been filled out.

The validation could be updated like this:

```
bool isValid = true;

switch (dropdown.SelectedValue)
{
    case "Option1":
        // check fields for Option1
        break;
    case "Option2":
        // check fields for Option2
        break;
    default:
        isValid = true;
}

args.IsValid = isValid;
```

Your next question might be, "how do I indicate which fields are invalid to the user?" There are a couple of different possibilities.

If the fields are grouped together visually on your UI, you could just update the CustomValidator's ErrorMessage to say "The XYZ fields are required." However, if they aren't, or if you would like to have a message for each invalid field, you could add a RequiredFieldValidator (or other validation as needed by a particular field) with the appropriate message and set the **[ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)** property (if it makes sense to group them), then, based on the selection, validate that particular group based on the dropdown selection.

If different fields can be associated with different dropdown options, the ValidationGroup idea won't be feasible. Instead you could probably have each fields' RequiredFieldValidator disabled, maintain a list for each of the fields' validators, and, in the switch statement, you can loop through them, enable them, call **[IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.isvalid.aspx)** on them (store the value in a bool and *AND* the results), then use the final bool result for the CustomValidator's args.IsValid property. An example of AND'ing the results can be seen in **[my reply to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421953/asp-net-gridview-validation-repeating-validation-messages-issue/1083671#1083671)**.

This approach can get very tricky and feel hacked together if you don't debug it properly because you need to be aware of all the enabling/disabling going on, otherwise you may find that you're unable to submit the page when everything appears valid on screen, but in actuality something was left enabled when you should've disabled all validators on each call before the switch, then enabled just the ones you need.